# Seblod template: How to use fields/markup.php to override field markup?

Tags: php, cck, seblod

I have created a new template by copying the `seb_one` template and then making my adjustments to `index.php`. I have also used `fields/markup.php` by copying it to `fields/contenttype/markup.php` in order to override how the fields are created.

In `fields/markup.php` I have commented out the logic and just put a `return $html;`

My problem is, this applies then to all fields in the contenttype. I would like to enable this override only for selected fields, or in particular, disable it for a certain field. Is there some variable or flag that I can pass with the field such that I can choose whether I ignore the markup or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in markup.php you can catch your field like next:

```
if($field->name == 'my_field')
{
  $html = "my code";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I just just realized that this is also possible without touching the `fields/_markup.php` file.

There are two options options that affect the markup of the field. First the field it self can be configured under the option 3 (markup + markup class), in the graphic marked with **A**. Setting this to `None`, will cause the field to be rendered without markup. This will preserve the label of the field but it does not any of the surrounding divs.

Second the variation of the position can be set to `- None -` and this will cause another remaining div for the position to be omitted.

[image: SEBLOD Markup configuration]